# Regular expression find command cygwin?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, find, cygwin

I've never been able to get regular expressions in Cygwin to work for me.
Here's some background info:
   -find (GNU findutils) 4.5.12
I have the following files in my directory:

```
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 None  0 Jun  4 19:16 eiooo.txt
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 None  0 Jun  4 19:20 g.py
-rwxrwx---+ 1 None 96 Jun  4 16:03 giibblejklxx_ekkwll.py
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 None  0 Jun  4 19:16 huuu.txt
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 None 20 Jun  4 19:17 more
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 None  0 Jun  4 19:20 v.py
```

I want to match strings whose ending is pys.
I try the following:

```
 find -name "*py$"
```

and I get nothing.

I also try:

```
 find -regex "*.py$"
```

and get nothing.

Am I using regular expressions correctly?  It was my understanding that the "$" means "ends with".  Is that true?  I know that I could leave the dollar sign out in this case, but I want to practice different kinds of regular expressions, and "$" (and "^", actually) never seem to work with the find command.

Any suggestions?  Thank.

Comment: I suppose another question might be:  Which version of regular expressions is  GNU findutils 4.5.12 using?

Comment: like I said in the question, I **know that I could leave out the dollar sign**.  But I want to know why it doesn't work with the dollar sign???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-name` and `-iname` use globs, not regular expressions. And `-regex` and `-iregex` will be false if the regular expression is invalid. Also note that `-regex` and `-iregex` attempt to match the entire path, not just the filename.

Comment: Aren't both regexes valid?  or no? "*"  means any number of any character, and  "$" means end of line.

Comment: "\*" means zero or more of the *preceding* character.